# Why is `each` in ruby not defined in the enumerable module?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Ruby defines most iterator methods in enumerable and includes that in Array, Hash etc.
However `each` is defined within every class and not included in enumerable.

Am guessing this was a deliberate choice but am wondering why?

Is there a technical limitation as to why `each` is not included in Enumerable?

Comment: How would you implement it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation for [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html):

> The Enumerable mixin provides collection classes with several traversal and searching methods, and with the ability to sort. **The class must provide a method each, which yields successive members of the collection.**

So the Enumerable module requires that classes which include it implement `each` on their own. All the other methods in Enumerable depend on `each` being implemented by the class which includes Enumerable.

For example:

```
class OneTwoThree
  include Enumerable

  # OneTwoThree has no `each` method!
end

# This throws an error:
OneTwoThree.new.map{|x| x * 2 }
# NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<OneTwoThree:0x83237d4>

class OneTwoThree
  # But if we define an `each` method...
  def each
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
  end
end

# Then it works!
OneTwoThree.new.map{|x| x * 2 }
#=> [2, 4, 6]
```